# Problems with installing nifty-generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, generator

I am trying to install nifty-generator gem - but have problem

When I put this command in my terminal I get this error-

```
gem "nifty-generators", :group => :development
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command nifty-generators,
```

Tried googling it but couldn't find a solution.

Ubuntu 10.04, Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: I found the solution to this problem. Actually I needed to edit the my own applications GEM file. Check this blog post here - http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/31/spinning-up-a-new-rails-app/

Answer (score 1):

Samir
You should write this string

```
gem "nifty-generators", :group => :development
```

in your Gemfile, located on yours rails application root folder. Then in terminal go to your apllication folder and execute

```
bundle install
rails g nifty:layout
```

and only then you can use all of advantages of this gem.

If you want to install "nifty-generators" from terminal, try

```
gem install nifty-generators
```